# Backend shuts down on system startup

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux, lighttpd, init

I use python on lighttpd (fastcgi). When I start server with `/etc/init.d/lighttpd start` everything works fine.

But now I've added it to system-v init with `update-rc.d lighttpd defaults 60` and after reboot I have this thing in error logs:

```
2011-03-24 22:57:01: (log.c.164) server started
2011-03-24 22:57:42: (mod_fastcgi.c.1754) connect failed: Connection refused on unix:/tmp/dvr.sock-0
2011-03-24 22:57:42: (mod_fastcgi.c.3021) backend died; we'll disable it for 1 seconds and send the request to another backend instead: reconnects: 0 load: 1
2011-03-24 22:57:55: (mod_fastcgi.c.2562) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 1509 socket: unix:/tmp/dvr.sock-0
2011-03-24 22:57:55: (mod_fastcgi.c.3299) child exited, pid: 1509 status: 1
2011-03-24 22:57:55: (mod_fastcgi.c.3346) response not received, request sent: 858 on socket: unix:/tmp/dvr.sock-0 for /dvr.fcgi?, closing connection
```

After `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart` it starts working properly.

Comment: Have deleted my answer, (I thought it was PHP related). However, nearly the same should apply to Python.

Comment: @hek2mgl, How would I know if you deleted it.

Comment: Oh, I thought, you as the OP can see it. (I can see it).. Posted the contents on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/vC9VLKex

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't heard anything about fastcgi manager for python.

Comment: You should, as lighthttpd is expecting it listening on `/tmp/dvr.sock-0` . Check this: http://www.electricmonk.nl/docs/apache_fastcgi_python/apache_fastcgi_python.html

Comment: There's `bin-path` option in lighttpd, lighttpd runs this script. I guess that's it. Anyway, I seriously don't think this is the problem because when I restart lighttpd it works fine. Maybe this issue is OS-related, I don't know. Weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to say that I used environment variable to choose settings file for my flask project. Of course this variable was set in `/etc/profile` that's why I was able to properly start project from shell.

So in my case I had to pass this variable to lighttpd using `bin-environment` option to make it available for fcgi script:

```
fastcgi.server = (
    "/dvr.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/dvr.sock",
            "bin-path" => "/var/www/dvr/conf/lighttpd/dvr.fcgi",
            "bin-environment" => (
                    "DVR_SETTINGS" => "/var/www/dvr/settings/production.py"
            ),
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "max-procs" => 1,
        )
    ),
)
```